# ¿Como cambio entre fragmentos en forma programática?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Quiero saber qué código puedo usar para ir de un fragmento a otro con un botón. Y de un fragmento a una vista.

Comment: Amigo, ¿Ya has buscado en Google? Te sugiero que busques un ejemplo y si tienes problemas con ello ya publicas tu código y tus errores aquí :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa las clases *FrameLayout* (una opción) y *ViewPager* en la documentación oficial. Despues puedes usar algo como:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frameLayoutContenedor,new MiFragment())
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```